# Filter Copy-Data source using variable

Tags: azure-data-factory

Scenario: I have multiple Views on a Azure SQL Database as source for a Copy Data pipeline. The Views contain data for multiple customers so I need the pipeline filtered by a customer ID.

I can do this using the Source query and just hard code the Customer ID but I'd like to make it more generic and use a variable to be set once and it be used to filter all the views. It is something that at first glance should be pretty straight forward.

Setting the variable is not a problem but I can't figure out the syntax to use in the Query. Or is there another mechanism I can use?

The basic pipeline (links as I can't embed yet):
[Basic Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZppo.png)

Filtering using this: [Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJCaZ.png)

Update:
Went with a solution very similar to Jay Gong below. Didn't use @Concat but assigned parameter to variable in SQL code and used in where clause. Will look into @Concat as I suspect it's slightly more efficient.

Comment: Do you mean you want set one variable to filter the source with View name and customer id in source dataset ?

Comment: I think you can set two parameters, view name and customer Id, then you can build an query in Source query to filter the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider passing parameters into ADF to complete query sql in source query blank.The sql could be dynamic content with [@concat built-in function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#concat).

For example:

[image]

[image]